# Changing month format from 1, 2 to Jan, Feb

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I have the following table:

```
data1
```

which produces:

```
month
1    -0.008999
2     0.032581
3     0.049919
4     0.072708
5    -0.037558
6    -0.017506
7     0.082839
8    -0.030190
9     0.006419
10    0.035679
11    0.065266
12    0.019905
Name: pct_day, dtype: float64
```

How can i make month into Jan, Feb ... instead of month 1, 2...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
import calendar
data1.month = data1.month.apply(lambda x: calendar.month_abbr[x])

or

data1.month = data1.month.apply(lambda x: calendar.month_abbr[int(x)])


Out[363]: 
0     Jan
1     Feb
2     Mar
3     Apr
4     May
5     Jun
6     Jul
7     Aug
8     Sep
9     Oct
10    Nov
11    Dec
Name: month, dtype: object
```

Comment: for some reason i am getting `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'month'` I have imported calendar

Comment: @newcoder it might be because you need to reset_index() or create pd,DataFrame(data1) from data1 first